# How to get a reference to a file

Tags: java, android

I need to make a reference to a `.txt` file, but I don't know what the `URL` to the file is? I have made an assets folder, because its not auto-generated in Android Studio, and placed my file there.

```
File file = new File(URL)
```

What is the URL to my file?

Comment: Why `res`? You should use `assets`, instead. Or `raw`. But I prefer `assets` anyway, since `raw` seems to be for media files while `assets` is more generic.

Comment: @Rotwang thanks, I changed where the file is and edited my question...

Comment: Then you can get the path by using `getAssets()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.txt")));
```

Check out [`AssetManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).